# Why does my UIStatusBar not display as desired through overriding preferredStatusBarStyle?

Tags: ios, presentmodalviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

My status bar acts accordingly in the root controller in each tab of my UITabBarController. Once I add a modal to the UIViewController through present(viewControllerToPresent:) with .overFullscreen modalPresentationStyle it requires me to assign the preferredStatusBarStyle through the UIViewController that sent it. I need the UIViewController being presented to have a clear background and see through to the previoues UIViewControllers content. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: "is consistently not the current one" ... Is it that the style isn't right, or is the title and the buttons are not right? Where are you in this tree where it's not right? What is the sequence of events that leads to an inconsistent status bar? Bottom line, I'd suggest backing up and a create [the smallest possible reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem rather than showing us some theoretical view controller hierarchy. We need reproducible example of the problem.

Comment: When you are going to present a modal, where should I present it from? Next question... Is there any pattern of modals (Almost everything past our initial tabbarcontroller is a modal.) that I can just know which View Controller is in charge of the status bar's color?

Comment: I have used debug view hierarchy, and without having more knowledge it doesn't directly answer my status bar question, unless I am ignorant to a feature it has that addresses this.

Comment: "where should I present [modal] from?" ... The current view controller (not anything up the view controller hierarchy). "Which view controller is in charge of the status bar's color?" ... The one you just presented modally. (Note, if you presented a navigation controller with a root view controller, you do this in the nav controller, not the navigation controller's root controller.) The exception is tab bar controllers, though, where the `preferredStatusBarStyle` comes from whatever view controller (or navigation controller) is associated with the tab, not the tab controller itself.

Comment: Again, we shouldn't have to guess what the question is here. You should tell us precisely where you are in your little picture, how you got there, and what precisely is wrong. We need reproducible example of the problem. Otherwise this question should be closed as being too broad and/or too unclear.

Comment: As an aside, I'm not sure why you're using navigation controllers if you don't `show`/`push`. It looks like you're doing modal `present` everywhere, so it's not clear what the navigation controllers are for. It also doesn't make sense to have the navigation controller `present` as shown in top right corner of your diagram/tree. You generally set root controller for the navigation controller. And when you present from there, you present from that root controller, not the navigation controller. Same with tab bar controllers; they don't `present` the associated view controllers.

Comment: I have them because it didn't always work this way and I work at a startup company where I find the need to make code transitions quickly more often then I would like. So the problem I am having with the status bar not responding in teh view controller I am inside of. I have experienced this issue in the past before AsyncDisplayKit. Could the issue be in that I am presenting the view controller using overFullscreen modalPresentationStyle in order to have a UIVisualEffectView as the visible background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue with a friend. The correct answer follows:

```
modalViewController.modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance = true
```